# Visual Studio Code becomes unresponsive after a short time

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm learning python using Visual Studio Code, A few minutes after opening a file VScode becomes unresponsive and sends a warning to the screen.

[image]

When I open Activity Monitor, while VScode is sluggish, it lists up to 5 processes named rg and up to five called Code Helper. Both processes are spawned by VScode and both are using over 100% of cpu time. I have to close the window and quit VScode before it returns to normal.  It just started exhibiting this behavior about a week ago, The file I'm working on is only 44 lines long. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening? I have an old iMac with 16 gigs of memory running High Sierra 10.13.5.